# Problemas para exportar valor recebido em função assíncrona

Tags: node.js, async, módulo-ecmascript

Estou tentando exportar um valor retornado em função assíncrona, mas ao executar no arquivo que importa, o objeto vem vazio.

```
    const results = [];

    async function run() {
      const client = new ResourceOwnerPassword(config);

      const tokenParams = {
        username: 'zzz',
        password: 'zzz',
        scope: 'zzz',
      };

      try {
        const accessToken = await client.getToken(tokenParams, {json: true});
        results.push(accessToken);
        return results
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Access Token Error', error.message);
      }

    }

    module.exports = results;
```

Answer (score -1):

Sua função em nenhum momento esta sendo executada, ele só está lendo a const, passa a função e já vai direto para o exports.

```
    const results = [];

    module.exports = async function () {
      const client = new ResourceOwnerPassword(config);

      const tokenParams = {
        username: 'zzz',
        password: 'zzz',
        scope: 'zzz',
      };

      try {
        const accessToken = await client.getToken(tokenParams, {json: true});
        results.push(accessToken);
        return results
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Access Token Error', error.message);
      }

    }
```

tente isso